# Mongo request with GeoJson Objects and multiple $near on different fields

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I am creating a carpooling app that offers a list of trips (Departure City -> Arrival City). 
I type the desired departure and arrival coordinates. And I get back the best options

My goal is to create a mongo request that return best routes that comes closest to my departure address and my arrival address

**Example:**

**Departure** Sèvres coordinates: [ 2.210590 , 48.824169 ]

**Arrival** Capbreton coordinates: [ -1.431370 , 43.640080 ]

I tried to combine this with $and operator but I'm not sure that is the solution... ("Too many geoNear expressions")

```
db.trip.find({
    $and: [
        {
            "departureLocation": {
                $near: {
                    $geometry: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: [ 2.210590 , 48.824169 ]
                    },

                }
            }
        },
        {
            "arrivalLocation": {
                $near: {
                    $geometry: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: [ -1.431370 , 43.640080 ]
                    },

                }
            }
        }
    ]
}, {"departure": 1, "arrival": 1})
```

Here my trips

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5d24d2e4ea5e2a29ea0f0e77",
        "departure": "Paris",
        "arrival": "Givrand",
        "departureLocation": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                2.352222,
                48.856613
            ]
        },
        "arrivalLocation": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -1.88465,
                46.67119
            ]
        },
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d3c594e6562967b8ad9e62b",
        "departure": "Bordeaux",
        "arrival": "Biarritz",
        "departureLocation": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -0.57918,
                44.837788
            ]
        },
        "arrivalLocation": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -1.558626,
                43.48315
            ]
        },
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d3c59e96562967b8ad9e62c",
        "departureLocation": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                2.18919,
                48.810032
            ]
        },
        "departure": "Chaville",
        "arrival": "Seignosse",
        "arrivalLocation": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -1.37524,
                43.69011
            ]
        },
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d3c5a8a6562967b8ad9e62d",
        "departureLocation": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -1.553621,
                47.218372
            ]
        },
        "departure": "Nantes",
        "arrival": "Hossegor",
        "arrivalLocation": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -1.3952,
                43.663342
            ]
        },
    }
]
```

**Expected result :**

(Chaville - Seignosse) should be placed at the first position of the result because it's the best option if I'm looking for a ride (Sèvres - Capbreton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, there's no mongodb-only solution to resolve this as:

- Only one $geonear expression can be used in a find() method.
- Only the first stage of an aggregation can be a $geonear stage.
- $geonear can not be used inside a $facet stage.

You have to deal with this programmatically, to run 2 separate geonear queries on your collection and find the best of the both resultsets. Before doing this, think about what is 'the best' result (closest to departure, arrival, lowest mean of both, etc...)

Comment: Yes this is correct, he can perform XOR operation on the filtered results from both sides. And get the matched from both.